# How to apply query / filter on a datasource related to the currently selected datasource?

Tags: filtering, relationship, google-app-maker

**Case:**

I have 3 datamodels:

- Tasks
- Sub-Tasks
- Status

The models are related in the following way: Tasks have a many-to-one with Statuses, same applies to Sub-Statuses. Some e.g. statuses are: To Do, Doing Done etc.

I can filter all Tasks using a dropdown with a set value of: "@datasource.query.filters." so that I select an option, only the records that have the specific value are shown.

I cannot use query on related datasources. E.g. if I want to apply query on "Tasks:Sub-Tasks(relation)", in order to filter the sub-tasks by their status (Sub-Tasks:Status(relation), query is missing as an option.

How can I achieve this? How can I apply a filter to related to the currently selected record items based on a specific to them attribute?

**Case 2**

How can a list based on multiple relationships be set up?

3 datasources:

- Stages
- Statuses
- Tasks

Tasks pass through stages, with its status changing along the way as well. E.g. Task can be in planning stage with status to do, doing or done.

Please refer to the added screenshot for an interface example.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately direct relation filtering is not supported in App Maker. You would need to set up a datasource for Subtasks that gets prefiltered on the current item in tasks and then you can implement further filters on this datasource. The other possible alternative is to try the JS filter function but I could not provide any detail on this since I’ve never tried it myself.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa thank you very much for the feedback! Do you have advice how I can set up a datasource to be prefiltered on the current item in tasks? For example: Can I set make 3 panels, all 3 to be with datasources Tasks: Sub-Tasks, but what separates them would be a filter based on their relationship Sub-Tasks:Status(relation). So that the panels would be: To Do, Doing, Done and the Sub-Tasks they show are based on that filter?

Answer (score 0):

This is only one possible solution. But I would suggest the following:

1. Create 3 datasources within Tasks Model, SubTasksToDo,
   SubTasksDoing, and SubTasksDone.
2. Within each datasource set the type to 'Query script' and add a
   parameter (type string or number depending on what your task primary
   key type is), call it 'MainTaskKey', and for each datasource uncheck
   the autoload option.
3. For each datasource enter a query script of:

   query.filters.YourMainTaskRelationEndName.id._equals = query.parameters.MainTaskKey;
   query.filters.Status._equals = 'To Do'; //replace with 'Doing' or 'Done' depending on which datasource you're working in
4. Go to your Main Tasks datasource and scroll down finding the
   onItemChange client script and enter the following in the code
   block:

   var itemKey = datasource.item.id;
   var todo = app.datasources.SubTasksToDo;
   var doing = app.datasources.SubTasksDoing;
   var done = app.datasources.SubTasksDone;
   todo.properties.MainTaskKey = itemKey;
   doing.properties.MainTaskKey = itemKey;
   done.properties.MainTaskKey = itemKey;
   todo.load();
   doing.load();
   done.load();
5. Then go to your page an insert a panel for each of the 3 SubTask
   datasources and put in a table or whatever you need.

Comment: Hello Markus, apologies for the late reply - I was trying to implement the solution but failed badly.

I receive the following error: "The function queryRecords returned undefined, please make sure a value was explicitly returned."

I was contemplating if a simpler solution is available to achieve the following:

A list showing stages, bellow statuses, and bellow them tasks depending on their stage and status. I'm including a crude screenshot of the possible interface for reference in the main case description.

How can such a list be set in the simplest manner possible?

Comment: @YesoYanchev it seems that I forgot return query.run() in each datasource for step 3. And my approach might be more difficult to implement with what you are looking for depending on how many stages you have. It would seem that you may be better of almost by using a separate model for stages but it’s hard to say.

Comment: I have come to a partial solution: 

When I apply a query script "query.filters.Stage.Stage._equals = 'Planning';
query.filters.State.State._equals = 'Pending';
return query.run();"

A panel with this datasource will load tasks filtered by those exact attributes. ISSUE!: unfortunately, the panel does not update when its stage or state are changed. It updates on page refresh, how can I make it update dynamically so it always retains the query script filter? I have tried using "Reload Datasource" on value change for drop-downs, not working for some reason.

Comment: @VesoYanchev You would want to introduce a parameter for Stage and one for State under your datasource and then instead of 'Planning' or 'Pending' you would want to say `query.parameters.YourParameterName`. Then bind your dropdown value(s) to `@datasource.query.properties.YourParameterName`. And you do want to retain the reload datasource for the dropdown onValueChange events.

Comment: All else is setup, but the dropdown value binding. Although I set it up to '@datasource.query.properties.YourParameterName', I receive the following error: "Invalid binding path: @datasource.query.parameters.Stage". Changing the value of the dropdown does not affect anything, The options of the dropdown are set to "@datasources.Stage.items.projections.Stage". Also previously the dropdown value was based on relation with Stage / State, with the change to dropdown value, the relationship is affected by the different values selected either.

Comment: You may have to play with the binding path a little. I don’t have AM in front of me at the moment but it may be @datasource.properties.YourParameter.

Comment: It seem this change has the same effect. I receive the following error: "Invalid binding path: @datasource.properties.Stage". Stage is the name of the parameter. The parameter is string, I am not sure if it should be something else. Same as the previous try - Using this for value for the dropdown does not reflect the relationship with Task at all unlike "@datasource.item.Stage".